# How to update a Shiny application only when the submit button is clicked?

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, shinyapps

I want to create a [shiny-app](/questions/tagged/shiny-app) that is updated only when the submit button is clicked. I looked a lot online to find an answer to my question an found this very useful webpage: (https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/action-buttons.html). I understand the code and I'm able to reproduce it, but when I use the same logic with my own code, the update button is useless and doesn't do anything.

Here's my code:

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)


ui <- fluidPage(

  checkboxGroupInput(
    inputId = "selected_dates",
    label = "Choose the year",
    choices = c("20","19","18","17","16","15"),
    selected = c("20","19","18","17","16","15")
  ),

  actionButton("go", "Update"),
  leafletOutput("map")

)

server <- function(input, output) {

  dates <- eventReactive(input$go, {
    input$years
  })

  output$map <- renderLeaflet({


    m <- addTiles(setView(leaflet(), lng = -73.731368, lat = 45.531368, zoom = 10))
    addCircles(m, data = vol_voiture[vol_voiture$Year %in% input$years,], lat = ~ LATITUDE, lng = ~ LONGITUDE, popup = ~ DATE, opacity = 0.5, weight = 0.1)

  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Just to clarify, `vol_voiture` is my [dataframe](/questions/tagged/dataframe). I know it's probably just a simple mistake or a misunderstanding from my part, but I've been working on this for many hours now and can't seem to find a solution. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Hi, can you add a subset of your data (with `dput`) so that your example is [reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? Try removing the expression where you define dates, and put all of `output$map <-...` inside `observeEvent(input$go, { ... })`. See [here](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/1.0.3/observeEvent.html) for more details on `observeEvent`

Comment: The section on "Dueling buttons" at https://shiny.posit.co/r/articles/build/action-buttons/ shows another way to include a start up display that is modified when an action button is used

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are not using your `eventReactive` function any where. I would try just replacing the `input$years` in the renderLeaflet call with `dates()`

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)


ui <- fluidPage(

  checkboxGroupInput(
    inputId = "selected_dates",
    label = "Choose the year",
    choices = c("20","19","18","17","16","15"),
    selected = c("20","19","18","17","16","15")
  ),

  actionButton("go", "Update"),
  leafletOutput("map")

)

server <- function(input, output) {

  dates <- eventReactive(input$go, {
    input$years
  })

  output$map <- renderLeaflet({

    m <- addTiles(setView(leaflet(), lng = -73.731368, lat = 45.531368, zoom = 10))
    addCircles(m, data = vol_voiture[vol_voiture$Year %in% dates(),], lat = ~ LATITUDE, lng = ~ LONGITUDE, popup = ~ DATE, opacity = 0.5, weight = 0.1)

  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Hope this helps!!

Comment: Thanks a lot, I was sure it was something dumb like this but I simply couldn't find it ! You're really helpful !