# How to get a Shiny reactive action button to activate date inputs?

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-reactivity

I'm building a Shiny app where I need to take inputted dates and use them in a section of code that only runs on a button click.

For the life of me I cannot find an example on here or in documentation that I can get to work.

**For the reprex example I simply want to print the inputted dates in the main panel once the 'Run Report' button is clicked.**

I've iterated the server code for hours, but cannot get this to work.

UI:

```
fluidPage(titlePanel('File download'),
          sidebarLayout(
            sidebarPanel(
              dateRangeInput(
                inputId = "date.range",
                label   = "Select Date Range",
                start   = Sys.Date() - 2,
                end     = Sys.Date() - 1
              ),
              actionButton(inputId   = "runReport",
                           label     = "Run Report")
            ),
            mainPanel(verbatimTextOutput("date.text"))
          ))
```

... and server:

```
function(input, output, session) {
  eventReactive(input$runReport, {
    output$date.text <- renderPrint({
      paste0(as.character(input$date.range[1]), "to", as.character(input$date.range[2]))
    })
  })
  
}
```

Comment: You don't need `eventReactive`.  Just include a reference to `input$runReport` in your `output$date.text`: `output$date.text <- renderPrint({ input$runReport;
      paste0(as.character(input$date.range[1]), "to", as.character(input$date.range[2]))
    })`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
ui <- fluidPage(titlePanel('File download'),
          sidebarLayout(
            sidebarPanel(
              dateRangeInput(
                inputId = "date.range",
                label   = "Select Date Range",
                start   = Sys.Date() - 2,
                end     = Sys.Date() - 1
              ),
              actionButton(inputId   = "runReport",
                           label     = "Run Report")
            ),
            mainPanel(verbatimTextOutput("date.text"))
          ))
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  dates <- eventReactive(input$runReport, {
    input$date.range
  })
  output$date.text <- renderPrint({
    paste0(as.character(dates()[1]), " to ", as.character(dates()[2]))
  })

}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

In what's above, you use `eventReactive()` to update the `dates()` object only when the button is pushed.  Then you do not need the reactive around the print statement because its inputs will automatically update when the button is pushed.  [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60907192/how-to-update-a-shiny-application-only-when-the-submit-button-is-clicked?rq=1) was instructive.